how to set marco to demerge cell and inset formula in a worksheet in different row
how to set marcos to demerge cell and inset formula in a worksheet in different row
to enable same formula copy from demerge cell in row 1 (blank color) to all row demerged cell
then change the text color to light grey.
I need a marcos with loop function to run more then 1000 row data

Please [edit] your question to include the application/programming language you are using.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
